# SSHFS , nginx and root permission issue

Tags: nginx, permissions, apache2, chown

I have 2 servers

Server A and Server B

Server A compress image, and put into Server B(Running Nginx)

The file put into Server B is through SSHFS(mounted) in a folder, when I go to Server B , I see the permission of the file is "root:root"

When I try to read it via web, it give a 403 forbidden.

So I did chown -R nginx:nginx on the folder itself. However new file, are still generated as "root:root"

Server A run Apache2 , while Server B run Nginx.

How do I make sure that my file in Server B is readable by Nginx, I cannot keep on go in and do the ownership change.

Is there a way I can change my nginx.conf to be able read the "root" file in this folder at /disk1/img

OR what else can I do to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're wanting to set the User and Group for SSHFS to `www-data:www-data` so that nginx owns it after the transfer.

Try this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/389161/how-to-set-up-sshfs-to-use-www-data